# How do I stop the capture using winpcap?

Tags: c, winpcap

```
/* start the capture */
pcap_loop(adhandle, 0, packet_handler, NULL);
```

The above starts the capture,but I don't find a way to stop the capture except exit the programe...

Answer (score 5):

Call [`pcap_breakloop()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html) in your `pcap_handler` (you've named it `packet_handler` in your example). The call to [`pcap_loop()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html) will then return `-2`.

Alternatively, make repeated calls to [`pcap_dispatch()`](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html) until you're done, or specify a nonzero value for `count` to handle that number of packets before returning.

Comment: Correct.
You can also use pcap_next_ex() to get a single packet (maybe in a loop).